# ValueError when trying to reconstruct CT images with ASTRA ToolBox

Tags: python, image, image-processing, tomography-reconstruction

I'm trying to reconstruct CT images stack, the number of images is 3500, the dimensions of each image is 2560*2160. I'm getting this error:
ValueError: The dimensions of the data do not match those specified in the geometry: (3500, 2160, 2560) != (2160, 2560)
Thanks for help!

```
import numpy as np
import astra
import tifffile
```

Load the TIFF file containing the CT data

```
data = tifffile.imread(r"E:\Norm.tif")
```

Define the reconstruction geometry

```
vol_geom = astra.create_vol_geom(data.shape[1], data.shape[2], data.shape[0])
```

Define the projection geometry

```
angles = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, data.shape[0], False)
proj_geom = astra.create_proj_geom('parallel', 1.0, data.shape[2], angles)
```

Create a projector object

```
proj_id = astra.create_projector('linear', proj_geom, vol_geom)
```

Create a sinogram from the CT data

```
sinogram_id, sinogram = astra.create_sino(data, proj_id)
```

Create a reconstruction object

```
recon_id = astra.data3d.create('-vol', vol_geom)
```

Set the parameters for the reconstruction algorithm

```
cfg = astra.astra_dict('SIRT3D_CUDA')
cfg['ProjectionDataId'] = sinogram_id
cfg['ReconstructionDataId'] = recon_id
cfg['option'] = {'MinConstraint': 0, 'MaxConstraint': 0.02}
```

Run the reconstruction algorithm

```
alg_id = astra.algorithm.create(cfg)
astra.algorithm.run(alg_id)
```

Get the reconstructed volume

```
recon = astra.data3d.get(recon_id)
```

Save the reconstructed volume as a TIFF file

```
tifffile.imwrite('reconstructed_volume.tif', recon)
```

Answer (score 0):

For 3D imaging, you need a [3D projector geometry](https://www.astra-toolbox.com/apiref/creators.html): `astra.create_projector('parallel3d',...`